# Create Dervice Instance by passing base instance

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

Hi This very basic level question. but i need to know what is the best way to handle this.

Parent class.

```
public class Parent {

    private String familyName;

    public Parent() {
    }

    public Parent(String familyName) {
        this.familyName = familyName;
    }

    public String getFamilyName() {
        return familyName;
    }

    public void setFamilyName(String familyName) {
        this.familyName = familyName;
    }
```

Child class.

```
   public class Child extends Parent {

    String name;

    public Child(Parent parent) {
       super(parent.getFamilyName());
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Child{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                "familyname='" + getFamilyName() + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Or Is there any support library to create child instance by cloning parent instance.

This is the way normally we can do. but this is ok when we have few attributes. 
but if we have a class with 100+ attributes we cant do this. its some thing ugly. 
So Is there any way to create child instance passing parent instance rather than setting attribute values one by one.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me a little bit confusing, that you have to pass a Parent class as a Parameter of Child and that you could have a class, that need so much input arguments in the constructor. Furthermore, you have to try passing field values, to hide the class inhritance, not the Parent class. Like:

```
public class Child extends Parent {

    String name;

    public Child(String name, String familyName) {
       super(familyName);
       this.name = name;
    }
    ...
}
```

Or you need to make a child having a Parent as a field, like:

```
public class Child  {

    String name;
    Parent parent;

    public Child(String name, Parent parent) {
       this.parent = parent;
       this.name = name;
    }
    ...
}
```

You can have some common interface for Parent and Child and use it for your purposes. Or even more, you can left it extending Parent class, but have it as the instance and override all the methods you need, like:

```
public class Child extends Parent {

    String name;
    Parent parent;

    public Child(String name, Parent parent) {
       super();
       this.parent = parent;
       this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getFamilyName() {
       return parent.familyName;
    }

    @Override
    public void setFamilyName(String familyName) {
        parent.familyName = familyName;
    }
    ...
}
```

But, IMO, you need to have a really valuable reasons to use such a solution, because it's not as straightforward as the usual one.

One more solution is to make an additional Parent constructor like:

```
public class Parent {

    private String familyName;

    public Parent() {
    }

    public Parent(Parent clone) {
        this.familyName = clone.familyName;
    }

    ...
}
```

And call it as:

```
public class Child extends Parent {

    String name;

    public Child(String name, Parent parent) {
       super(parent);
       this.name = name;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply. but sorry. this is not i expected. i want to create child instance using parent instance but cant set attribute values one by one. I mean i need some thing like create child instance by cloning parent instance.

Comment: ok, why don't you simply create a Parent's constructor, which will get a Parent instance and set the fields needed. This will cause you to modify this constructor ince you've added some new field. Anyway, you have to think about your design, if you want to use 3rdparty libs against native OOP princips.

Comment: this very simple example i get. suppose as  i mention the class have 100+ attributes we have to set one by one. i want this when we have such a object.

Comment: Just use some 3rd party libs in the Parent constructor, to let em initialize your fields. Like http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/
But you will not break the OOP design by it. It'll be just implementation of parent constructor

Comment: Take a closer look at http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.2/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#copyProperties(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)

Comment: But you have to understand, any 3rd party solution for copying the fields will use reflection and it could lead to perfomance problems. Especially, if your objects will be created very often. Any native solution with field settings, even if the number of fields is great, will be much more faster and in most cases is preffered.